# SQL Server 2017 Express Edition Insert Select Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-express

**Command 1:**

```
Select Count(*) From View1

Results:
-----------
183

(1 row affected)
Execution time = 11 seconds
```

**Command 2:** (store the count in a table called Temp)

```
Drop Table Temp

Create Table Temp
(
  C Int
)

Insert Temp
Select Count(*) From View1

(1 row affected)
Execution time = 29 sec
```

My Question:

I am unable to understand why SQL Server takes 11 seconds for **Command 1** and 29 seconds for **Command 2**?

The only difference between **Command 2** and **Command 1** is, we are storing the result of SELECT in **Command 2**. The result is only a single value = 183.

Drop and Create Of Temp takes 0 ms. There are no indexes or constraints on Temp.

Comment: You need to check execution plans for both scenarios

Comment: Running on laptop?

Comment: Execution plan is same as the SELECT is same in both cases. Only difference is INSERT. I can show it happening on my desktop.

Comment: There is no other major disk or network activity that could slow the INSERT SELECT. This is my personal computer (standalone).

Comment: There is enough free space in the DB files. No issue of disk space.

Comment: I'm amazed by the time difference between the 2 commands. Also, 11 seconds is more than the majority of SELECT's, but could of course be correct for a complicated view, or when dealing with lots of data. Are you surprised by the 11 seconds, or is that timing as expected? Another thing: Could the time difference be explained by some anti-virus software kicking in when you do inserts (disk-writes)?

Comment: The View has a complicated SELECT, so 11 seconds is expected. But 29 seconds for INSERT SELECT is not expected. @Morten, disk activity is not a bottleneck (<50%). I do not think its anti-virus issue.

Comment: I have disabled the Anti-Virus, firewall. Closed all apps, only SSMS is running.

Created a new database. Created the required tables and view. Populated data in the tables in new database from the old database.

Switched the new database to single-user mode. Ran Command 1 and Command 2 on new database. Command 1 takes the same 11 seconds, Command 2 takes the same 29 seconds.

Network activity, Disk activity, CPU activity and Memory usage is minimal due to any other apps or processes.

Also I reproduced the same issue on SQL Server 2012 Express. @LukaszSzozda.

Comment: How long time does it take if you rewrite command 2 into 2 statements: First fetch the count into a declared variable, then in the next statement insert the variable into the table?

Comment: declare @c int
drop table Temp
create table Temp
(
 C Int
)

Select @c = COUNT(*) From InsPerf

Insert Temp
Select @c     Execution Time is 11 seconds

Comment: Storing in a variable and then storing in table Temp takes 11 seconds. Same as Command 1.

Comment: That was what I suspected. My guess is that behind the scenes SQL Server runs the query multiple times when it has to insert the count directly, but by storing the count in a variable you force SQL Server to just run the query once. Could you use this solution as a work-around in your case?

Comment: @SharatGupta Please try: 
`Select Count(*) AS c INTO Temp From View1`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Tried what you said. `Select Count(*) AS c INTO Temp From View1`. Execution Time = 29 seconds. Same as Command 2.

Comment: @Morten I have studied the execution plan. The SELECT query is executed only once in INSERT SELECT, and then in the end there is a Table Insert operator. Thats the way it should be. First build the result set from the SELECT and then Insert into Temp.

Comment: @Morten I can store the count in a variable and then store the variable in the table as a work around. This work-around will not work if the code is like `Insert Temp Select * From View1`. Here Temp has the same structure as View1. I have tried `Insert Temp Select * From View1`, execution time is 29 s, same as Command 2. Also tried, `Select * From View1` returns 183 rows of data in 11 seconds.

Comment: Rebooted the machine. Started only SSMS. Ran the commands. Same result. Command 1 takes 11 seconds. Command 2 takes 29 seconds.

Comment: `DECLARE @cnt INT; SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM View1; INSERT INTO Temp(C) SELECT @cnt;`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Executed your code. Execution time is 11 seconds. Same as Command 1. In a earlier comment ( 19 hours ago from now ) I said, storing the result of the SELECT in a variable and then storing the variable in Temp takes 11 seconds. Morten had asked me to try that. Also, in a earlier comment ( 11 hours ago from now ) I said, what I  actually wanted to do was  `Insert Temp Select * From View1` (takes 29 seconds). Here Temp and View1 have same columns. Executed `Select * From View1` returns 183 rows in 11 seconds. I used COUNT(*) for a better focus.